# How to put columns in file

Tags: c++, c

I have a file and I want to insert data in it as columns like this:

Column size: 5spaces  5spaces  12 spaces

```
25100 23501 169247103621
```

But I still have this **two conditions**:

1. If the string bigger then the column size, I eliminate the odd
   length from the string.
2. If the string smaller then the column size, I fill the rest of
   string with spaces.

**Ex1:**

```
2510025 23501 169247103621
```

Become:

```
25100 23501 169247103621
```

**Ex2:**

```
25 23501 169247103621
```

Become:

```
25    23501 169247103621
```

I manged to get this in c with `printf`, but now I want print some format in a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char FMT[] = "%-5.5s %5s %-6.12s\n";
   FILE *hFile = NULL;
   char *string  = "freeifaddrss";
   char *string2 = "cards";
   char *string3 = "ifa_nextifa_next";
   printf(FMT, string, string2, string3);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write to a file you can either redirect the output of your program, eg:

```
./prog > out.txt
```

or open a file in the program and write to that:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "w");
if (f == NULL) {
     perror(argv[1]);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...
fprintf(f, FMT, string, string2, string3);
```

Call this with:

```
./prog out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try ?

```
fp = fopen( "output.txt", "w" );
if( fp != NULL )
  fprintf( fp, "Hello %s\n", name );
```

Comment: @Senthis I don't just want to write to a file, rather then I want to write to a file with a specific format. Please re-read my question to understand what I want exactly.

Comment: I meant you can use the same format that you have used in printf.